# Why push shows argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet

In this code i get the fallowing error:

> Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'never'

```
var markers: [];
this.Getlapoints(this.map.getCenter(), 500000).then(data => {
  for (var key in data) {
    Leaflet.marker(data[key].location, //{ icon: greenIcon            }
    ).addTo(this.map).bindPopup(data[key].caption);
    // markers.push(data[key].location.lat,data[key].location.lng);
    // markers.push(data[key].location);

    var lat = data[key].location.lat;
    var lng = data[key].location.lng;
    markers.push([lat, lng]);
  }
  console.log(markers);
});
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

With `var markers: []` you are declaring the `markers` array as having the type of a permanently empty array.  You probably meant `var markers = []` to initialize it to empty but allow items to be added.

Comment: thanks, this is the answer to my problem, but I was only able to surmount it like this: `let all: any[] = []`

Answer (score 69):

Change this :

```
const a = [];
```

By this :

```
const a = Array();
```

Comment: I believe this should be made as the accepted answer !

Comment: But why... ? aren't these 100% the same?

Answer (score 7):

In tsconfig.json -

```
 "noImplicitReturns": false,

 "strictNullChecks":false,
```

[image]

Solution: type as 'never'

[image]

Comment: Turning off the check is not a fix

Answer (score 1):

> The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself). Even any isn’t assignable to never.

From the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never)

Comment: I don't what are you suppose to do. You can replace the `never` with `null` or empty string or 'never' (as string).

Comment: I want to store all posts latlang in array to use in leaflet, LatLngBounds to fit all markers in map view.